# Reuse components in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

As a new AngularJS developer (coming from PHP+Laravel world) I'm facing some troubles designing the architecture of my new app.
Which is the best way to implement a CRUD app where entities are used more than once along the app?

For example: we have the entities 'document' and 'project'. Documents can be listed and viewed alone, but also can be attached to projects. Inside the project detail view I would like to include the attached documents, using the same template used when listing the documents alone. This widget should have its own controller and methods, since its need to make some API calls and apply some business logic; and receive the parent project data in some way.

What should I use for document listing? A directive, a ng-include or some other?

Answer (score 1):

You should use module to use it as reusing component.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Answer (score 1):

i'm utilizing angular `module` and `factory` like this:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
/* App Module */

var app = angular.module('my-app', [

    'my-models',

]);
```

**my-models.js**

```
var myModels = angular.module('my-models', []);


myModels.factory('DocumentsModel', function ($http)
{
    var DocumentsModel = function ()
    {
    };

    DocumentsModel.get_documents = function (page, results_per_page)
    {

        var data = {
            page: page,
            results_per_page: results_per_page
        };

        var json = angular.toJson(data);

        return $http.post('/api/documents', json);
    };

    DocumentsModel.set_document_state = function (document_id, document_state_id)
        {
            var json = angular.toJson(
                {
                    'document_state': document_state_id
                }
            );

            return $http.post('api/document/'+document_id', json);
        };

    return DocumentsModel;
});
```

using angular dependency injection mechanism, you can re-use this logic in multiple controllers by adding `DocumentsModel` to the controller function as parameter:

**documents-ctrl.js**

```
var app = angular.module('my-app');

var controller = app.controller("DocumentsCtrl",
    function ($scope, DocumentsModel)
    {

        DocumentsModel.get_documents()
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.documents = data.documents;
            });

    });
```

in addition, you cad define one for your 'project' entity.

---

### Edit:

Javier commented:

[image]

assuming your documents response is

```
[{name: ... , size: ... , last_modified: ... }, {name: ... , size: ... , last_modified: ... }, ...]
```

you can utilize `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="document in documents">
            <td>{{ document.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ document.size/1024 | number:4 }} MB</td>
            <td>{{ document.last_modified | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: And what should I use to render the document listing inside a project template?

Comment: @JavierMarín, added example with ng-repeat

Comment: I was thinking of some 'document widget' that I can use alone when listing documents, or inside a 'project' template, for list all project documents.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it as a dependency to your own module. Like

```
angular.module('test', []);

angular.module('test2', ['test']);
```

You might want to take a look at [`Yeoman`](http://yeoman.io/)